# excecute a php file inside an 'if' condition

Tags: php, soap, foreach

I have to execute some code in a loop, but every time I try to put all of it in the loop below, the result set gets crazy, giving me unreal data.
So I figured to try to put the loop out of my code. I tried this code:

```
include 'soapproxy.php';

$proxy = SoapProxy::login("astar", "Astar2012", "48");
$xmlusers = $proxy->getUsersInGroup("vehicles", 0); 
foreach($xmlusers->user as $user) {
    if($user->id > 1){
        include 'send_data_to_db.php?user=$user->id';
    }
}
```

It doesn't do the job. What is wrong?

Comment: Why not creating a class for sending data and summon the function?
I don't know why but I don't love the idea of including a file in a loop.

Comment: @OfirBaruch this is so wrong on many levels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
include 'soapproxy.php';

$proxy = SoapProxy::login("astar", "Astar2012", "48");

$xmlusers = $proxy->getUsersInGroup("vehicles", 0); 

foreach($xmlusers->user as $user) {
    if($user->id > 1 {
        $user = $user->id; // or try $_GET['user'] = $_REQUEST['user'] = $user->id; if the included script MUST have the data inside $_GET or $_REQUEST.
        include 'send_data_to_db.php';
    }
}
```

Include will simply take the files content and parse it as if it was just inside the current file. You can not add arguments to an include call

But the real best solution would be, as Rath said, to edit send_data_to_db.php , and make the contents of it to be a function, that takes $user as an argument. Then you would do something like:

```
include 'soapproxy.php';
include 'send_data_to_db.php'; // just include it once

$proxy = SoapProxy::login("astar", "Astar2012", "48");

$xmlusers = $proxy->getUsersInGroup("vehicles", 0); 

foreach($xmlusers->user as $user) {
    if($user->id > 1 {
        the_function_in_send_data_to_db.php($user->id); // call the function you created in the file multiple times
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot nl-x !! this worked like sharm! :))

Comment: @Mihaila you're welcome. which solution did you take? The `$user=...`, the `$_GET['user']=...`, or the function approach?

Comment: I toke the function approach and it worked perfectly! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you need to break your code into multiple files, the best answer to your problem is to not include the file in every iteration but define a function within the new file and call the function instead. (that's why God invented functions, otherwise we'd be including files everywhere). Using `include` can work but looks like an ugly hack.

Comment: I just upvoted your answer but did God really invent functions? or we did? :)

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ OMG. Of course God did! Blasphemy! Next thing you'll be saying is that OOP is part of evolution. :/

Comment: God invented C, ergo God invented functions (all those who say functions existed before C are blasphemers)